# Issue in MainWindow.XIB after compiling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.2, xib

I have an application that is not archived on XCode 4.2 as it contains mailcore framework but I have done successful archive on XCode 3.2 after done changes in the Library and header search Paths. But now When I am doing changes in its MainWindow.XIB file like by adding the Label or any other control and compiling after saving the project gives me error..

**CompileXIB MainWindow.xib**

**Not enough arguments provided; where is the input document to operate on?**

and on expanding all transcripts in XCode 3.2, it gives me some what detailed description of the error, hope it is more helpfull ..

```
CompileXIB MainWindow.xib
cd /Users/amitbattan/Desktop/jony/Test/SampleApplication
setenv IBC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 4.2
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices all_load --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/amitbattan/Desktop/Vikas/iRCS_Nov_8_4/RCS/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iRCS.app/MainWindow.nib /Users/amitbattan/Desktop/Vikas/iRCS_Nov_8_4/RCS/MainWindow.xib --sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk

/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
: error: Not enough arguments provided; where is the input document to operate on?
```

So, I have no idea why this error occurs and How can I come out with this error..

Thanks

Comment: More info required: Go to the *Log Navigator* (left pane, rightmost button), select the *Build MyProject*, then the line that builds the `.xib` and then press the button on the far right (icon with all lines). Then paste all the text that shows into your question.

Comment: yes Thanks.. I have tried to give more info.. hope it is more helpful.

Comment: And `.../iRCS_Nov_8_4/RCS/MainWindow.xib` exists?

Comment: Run that command from `Terminal` and see what happens.

Comment: Please provide me link which command .. or your link is not active..

Comment: Huh?  Copy that command from above and paste it into Terminal (shell) and see what happens.

Comment: @trojanfoe Which command I did not find.. can you please show me that command. Is it this one /Users/amitbattan/Desktop/jony/Test/SampleApplication

Comment: It's the one starting `/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings...`.  You know the one that compiles the `.xib` file.

Comment: No.After running the command I get this ../* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
: error: Not enough arguments provided; where is the input document to operate on?

Comment: And `ls -l /Users/amitbattan/Desktop/Vikas/iRCS_Nov_8_4/RCS/MainWindow.xib` shows what?

Comment: it shows.. -rwxrwxrwx  1 amitbattan  staff  5283362 Nov  8 14:21 /Users/amitbattan/Desktop/Vikas/iRCS_Nov_8_4/RCS/MainWindow.xib

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19272/discussion-between-vikas-ahuja-and-trojanfoe)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a compatibility issue.  I think the `.xib` has moved to Xcode 4 (as shown by the line `setenv IBC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 4.2`) which Xcode 3.2's version of `ibtool` does not understand.

I think you need to revert to a version of the `.xib` prior to the update to Xcode 4.